# Difference in coordinates of a location in Google Earth and QGIS Canvas

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS, I am using WGS 84 UTM 43 EPSG 3263 for both Project and Basemap of Google Satellite Hybrid.

Now when I navigate to my home location in Basemap, with Lat Lon tool I captured the coordinates which showed me this result:
2825537.85691968, 8206411.02187792

But when I go on Google Earth and navigate to my same home location, I get these coordinate details in degree:
Latitude 24.590745°, Longitude 73.719637°

[image]

Why is QGIS not showing coordinate values as Google Earth? How to convert latitude and longitude values in degrees to the values compatible with QGIS canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project - Properties - General and change the `display coordinates` option to `WGS 84 - degree`. For more details, check the [official doumentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#project-properties:%7E:text=Available%20parameters%20are%3A).

Comment: I did it. And it is displaying coordinate in degree form in status bar. But the problem is this that still the coordinates which are displayed when I roll over to my home location are not as my home location in google earth

Comment: 24.59°N 73.71°E points to the area depicted in your screenshot. Where do you end up when entering those coordinates @HNA?